# Implementing a LIP/MILP solver by myself

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I am interested in trying to implement a (simple) LP and MILP solver by myself, mainly for educational purposes.

Meaning, I don't want to use Cplex/Gurobi/CBC, etc, I want to "develop" a simple toy version of them.

I was unable to find much guidance on the web, and would appreciate if anyone could direct me to sources of information or guides.

Thank you

Comment: Try reading your question as if you were not the author. Then read the guidelines for questions. Then please [edit] it and make it more clear-cut what you are asking for... as it stands it will most likely be closed as off topic...

Comment: Consult a textbook, e.g. https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-39415-8